# $ is not defined while use jquery code in express.js at parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, parse-platform

I think this issue getting because jquery not working,so please help me how can implement jquery in my `main.js` (express.js controller ) at `parse.com`

**What i want to do**

Download image from `parse cloud` and further render that image in `view template` `(in .ejs file)`

but i got `$ is not defined` in parse.com log

I have also added  line  `require('cloud/jquery.min.js');`

**my code**

```
 /**
 * get user image
 */
app.get('/getUserImageAction',function(req,res){
var Documents = Parse.Object.extend("Documents"); // Documents class
var query = new Parse.Query(Documents); 
query.equalTo("imageOwner","234");
query.find({
success: function(imgObjects) {
var documentImage = imgObjects[0].get("imageFile");

$("documentImage")[0].src = documentImage.url();
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: documentImage.url()      }).then(function(response) {
// The file contents are in response.buffer.
   res.render('viewDocuments.ejs',{image:response.buffer});
  });
  },
 error: function(object, error) {
  res.render('hello.ejs',{message:+ error.code + " : " + error.message});

}
});
});
```

**2) second is when comment that line**, I am getting something in `imgObjects` but got this error at parse log.

**Result: Script ran out of memory**

Comment: Where did you get from the jQuery library? Is it a nodejs module?

Comment: i have deployed `jquery.min.js` in parse.com  cloud folder and this code puts in main.js

Comment: This is the jQuery library for nodeJs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery

Comment: I have execute this command ` npm install jquery` but at which location installed and should deploy again that file on parse.

Comment: its resolved now.!! enjoy coding.