# Getting images from my Parse database in javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, image, file, parse-platform

I have images stored in a parse database under the column image.

Using a query and the .get("image") command, I can get an [OBJECT object] type of thing returning in the js.

So how do I use this object to actually show the image?

*image.getUrl() tells me .getUrl() isn't a function so I guess it isn't that*

Comment: I am working on same but i can't able to run jquery code please refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762306/is-not-defined-while-use-jquery-code-in-express-js-at-parse-com) my question and help me

Comment: just check it with image._url

Comment: thanks but its resolved now hurrrra.!!

Comment: @VRK thanks very much, you were right! not sure why I couldn't find that info online...

Comment: the link posted by @Quentin doesn't work anymore, you'd want to look at the documentation link posted in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you see your return image object and stringify it you will get all details about image.

so the image URL is

```
image._url
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for getting a Parse a file or image is here in the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#files-retrieving-file-contents).

```
object.get("image").url()
```

Hope this helps!